# connectionString Rede local Asp.Net MVC SQL SERVER

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server, connectionstring

Estou tentando conectar um banco na minha aplicação, que está em rede, então eu coloquei o seguinte caminho:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="smc" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.0.29; Initial Catalog=nomeDoBanco; User=sa; Password=senhaDoBanco" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

erro da aplicação:

> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): Acesso negado]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): Erro de rede ou específico à instância ao
>   estabelecer conexão com o SQL Server. O servidor não foi encontrado ou
>   não estava acessível. Verifique se o nome da instância está correto e
>   se o SQL Server está configurado para permitir conexões remotas.
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Não foi possível abrir
>   uma conexão com o SQL Server)]

erro quando tento acessar pelo gerenciador
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, da erro. Alguém sabe se eu preciso informar algo mais no Data Source, ou se eu tenho que configurar alguma coisa no banco?

Comment: Rafael, qual a mensagem de erro, poderia inseri-la na pergunta?

Comment: No ambiente em que você se encontra, você tentou acessar pelo Management Studio com as credenciais informadas e conseguiu? Edita a pergunta e inclui o erro que ocorreu.

Comment: Editei a pergunta e coloquei o erro, de quando acesso pela aplicação, e de quando tento acessar via gerenciador.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Era apenas configuração do do MSSQL SERVER.
Se alguém passar pelo mesmo problema, segue um tutorial que me ajudou

http://www.systematiza.com.br/site/?page_id=837